# Output of for each loop on SimpleXMLElement Object array, one node further in then outside the loop

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am trying to loop through an array created by simplexml_load_file, when accessing the array outside of my for each loop I get expected results,

```
print_r ($feedobject->Item[0]->attributes())`;
```

Output:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 202fnl
            [TableID] => newitem
        )
)
```

When accessing via my for each loop

```
foreach ($feedobject->Item[$x] as $value) {
    print_r ($value->attributes());    
$x++;
}
```

I get unexpected results (one step further into the array)

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [TableFieldID] => description
            [Value] => Our 2-ounce plastic funnel is the perfect fit for our 8-ounce stainless steel flasks. It works!
        )
)
```

Xml file looks like

```
  <Item ID="202fnl" TableID="newitem">
        <ItemField TableFieldID="description" Value="Our 2-ounce plastic funnel is the perfect fit for our 8-ounce stainless steel flasks. It works!"/>
```

Why does this happen and does any one have a better suggestion for looping through specific elements of this array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting confused on the element selection. To get each `<Item>`, just use `$feedobject->Item`.

```
// select each `<Item>`
foreach ($feedobject->Item as $value) {
    echo $value->attributes()->ID;
}
```

When you use `$feedobject->Item[$x] as $value`, this already points directly to elements inside `<Item>` which shows you `<ItemField>`.

Comment: Got the correct output after that, thank you very much.

Comment: @GreggoryWiley sure glad this helped